# I would like to be able to play my guitar along with songs I have in iTunes and listen to a mix in my headphones

Tags: electric-guitar

I would like to be able to play my guitar along with songs I have in iTunes and listen to a mix in my headphones. I have a PC, and Protools LE, but I don't know if it's possible to monitor the playlist & play along. I'd rather not have to import a song separately into Protools

Comment: What platform? What's your audio interface? Most interfaces can do this without needing to go through the computer at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set up the equipment I have so I can play the guitar with a backing track (laptop) and using headphones?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/121422/how-can-i-set-up-the-equipment-i-have-so-i-can-play-the-guitar-with-a-backing-tr)

Comment: The operating system is windows 10.  The interface is a MBOX Pro 2

Comment: All sounds are mixed by the system itself in the end. It's called multiplexing. You should be able to do this by directing iTunes to the same interface you use for guitar input. At the very least, you should be able to set a _default_ audio device (for all non-pro apps)